# CasperJS error - undefined is not a function (this.waitForUrl)

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a casperJS script that does some form filling and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.waitForUrl')
```

Is this due to using an outdated version? I'll try to find out what version is running and post back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely due to an outdated version.

The [docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforurl) specify that version 1.1 is required, however it hasn't been officially released yet.

You can download the [latest release](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/releases) (1.1-beta2 at the time of this writing)

However, if you want to get all the latest features and bug fixes, you may want to use the latest [master branch](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs).